# Problemas al hacer push

Tags: git, github

Estoy intentando hacer un push a un repo pero al ejecutar el push al repositorio me aparece

```
 ! [rejected]        development -> development (non-fast-forward)
error: falló el push de algunas referencias a 'https:...'
ayuda: Actualizaciones fueron rechazadas porque una punta de rama en el push está 
ayuda: detrás de su contraparte remota. Verifique esta rama e integre los cambios remotos
ayuda: (ejem. 'git pull ...') antes de volver a hacer push.
ayuda: Vea las 'Notes about fast-forwards' en 'git push --help' para más detalles.
```

Comment: Hubo cambios por otra rama, has `git pull` y revisa si no hay conflictos, si los hay entonces has otro commit y luego `git push`

Comment: @JonathanOrta acabo de hacer un pull y me sale que ya esta actualizado

Comment: Lo más probable es que se haya alterado la historia del repo, ya sea debido a un commit/push hecho **antes** de haber actualizado con `git pull` o un commit editado **después** de haber hecho `git push`. ¿Podrías añadir la salida del comando `git log --graph --oneline --all --decorate`? para ver cómo están las relaciones entre los commits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El problema se soluciono, borrando el repositorio local de mi computador y clonandolo de nuevo, ya que ni reset --hard, ni otros comandos pudieron arreglar el problema para hacer el push.

Answer (score 1):

Este error seguramente se debió a que hicieron un rebase del branch development, por lo que el commit en el que estabas trabajando ya no existe más en el árbol de git en el server.
En este caso puedes hacer:

```
git pull --rebase
```

**Advertencia:** ¡esto probablemente sobreescribirá todos sus archivos actuales con los archivos como están a la cabeza de la rama en el repo remoto!

Te dejo el link que explica como se debe trabajar con branches y rebase.

https://git-scm.com/book/es/v2/Ramificaciones-en-Git-Reorganizar-el-Trabajo-Realizado